# Change a var inside a function, but not use it

Tags: javascript, jquery

1- I Declare a var outside any function
2- I click and I supose I change the var to BMW? (but I do not show it)
3- I click to another place and I want to show the var I thought it would show BMW but it shows Maserati. Why? If I change a var inside a click function but I do not use the var, does the var really change? Can someone explain please, I just want to understand the behaviour.

Here to check and play: http://jsfiddle.net/gLe5305k/

jQUERY:

```
var carName = "Maserati";

$("#blue").click(function() {
    var carName = "BMW";
}); 

$("#smoke").click(function() {
    $('#check').text( carName);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="smoke"></div>

<div id="check"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blue{
    position: absolute;
    top:100px; left:100px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:blue;
}

#smoke{
    position: absolute;
    top:100px; left:250px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:whiteSmoke;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont declare the variable again:

```
$("#blue").click(function() {
    carName = "BMW";
});
```

If you declare the variable again, it will be treated as a local variable with the scope limited to that function.

Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/farhans/tw2667sy/)

Comment: This would be a great answer if you explained the OP why using `var` inside his function doesn't update the global var `carName`.

Comment: To make Global a var inside a function, I should nor use 'var', is that the rule?

Comment: By not using `var`, you do not declare the variable in the scope of the function, it will look in outer scopes until it finds your variable. When you use `var` to declare it inside the function, the outer variable is effectively hidden, and you'd have to access it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables of the same name but different scope.

Change `var carName = "BMW";` to `carName = "BMW";`

Now you just have the one variable